# I want to navigate to Another page after I click Login

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I use .Net as back-end and now im working with angular for routing part i'm stuck in navagite to another page using authentication I supposed to use
navigate router after subscribe  but I don't know how

```
export class LoginComponent {

  title = 'webUI.UI';
  user = new User();

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  
  login(user: User) {
    this.authService.login(user).subscribe((token: string) => {
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem('authToken') != null){
??????
      
    }
  }
}
```

my router

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},


{

  path: 'signup',
    component: SignupComponent
},

{
  path: 'home',
  component: EmployeepListComponent
},
```

Comment: i tried to fixed like you said but I got this error??
       ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'

Comment: Please don't spam the tags. [angular] is for questions about Angular 2+, the modern framework. [angularjs] is for questions about AngularJS 1.x, a deprecated framework. [Edit] your question accordingly. Also, rather than adding comments with clarifications, [edit] the question to include the clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Guard`, too for this. Read more [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). The `canActivate`guard can protect any component inside your router. So you can check your token or anything and then redirect to login, or the page the user want to navigate.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const token = this.auth.getToken();
    const url = "/token/verify/";

    if (!token) {
      this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
      return false;
    }

    return this.auth.verifyToken().pipe(
      tap(allowed => {
        if (!allowed) this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auth-guard-example-stack-overflow?file=src/app/can-activate.guard.ts) is a Stackblitz example.

Answer (score 0):

Do that in the `ngOnInit` in app component :

```
ngOnInit(){
  if (localStorage.getItem('authToken') != null){
    this.router.navigete(['login'])
   }
}
```

or in the login function do that :

```
login(user: User) {
 this.authService.login(user).subscribe((token: string) => {
    if(token !=null)  {
       localStorage.setItem('authToken', token); 
       this.router.navigate(['otherPath'])
     }
  });
}
```